# Using a Nested-Model form as a Partial on a different models's page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a nested model form for PhotoAlbums. The form works fine via the standard html. But what I need to do is render it as a partial in another page it's erroring: "No route matches

```
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"photo_albums"}"
```

The models:

```
Projects 
  has_many :photo_albums 
PhotoAlbums 
  belongs_to :project 
  has_many :photos 
Photos 
  belongs_to :photo_album 
Controller: 
  def create 
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
    @photoalbum = PhotoAlbum.create(params[:photo_album]) 
  end
```

Here is the working form which loads and works find via HTML:

```
<% form_for [:project, @photoalbum], :html => { :multipart => true } 
do |f| %> 
        <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :title %><br /> 
                <%= f.text_field :title %> 
        </div> 
        <% f.fields_for :photos do |builder| %> 
                <% if builder.object.new_record? %> 
                        <%= builder.label :photo, "photo File" %> 
                        <%= builder.file_field :photo %> 
                <% end %> 
        <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

The issue I'm having, is that to render this form as a partial in a 
view in another page. I'm using the following:

```
<% @photoalbum = PhotoAlbum.new %> 
<%= render :partial => "photo_albums/form",  :locals => 
{:photoalbum => @photoalbum}  %>
```

I checked by Rake Routes, And I do have it there:

project_photo_albums POST   /projects/:project_id/

```
photo_albums(.:format) 
{:controller=>"photo_albums", :action=>"create"}
```

Thoughts? thank you

Comment: Thanks Peter, I didn't know about the routes tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form you have:

```
form_for [:project, @photoalbum]
```

but it seems that your partial only gets the @photoalbum variable. What about the project variable?